# Plot anomaly temperature graph using monthly data by R

Tags: r

Can I plot anomaly temperature graph using monthly temperature data by R? I do not have daily temperature data. My data is like this:

```
1 8.2 JAN-1990
2 5.3 JAN-1991
3 6.2 JAN-1992
4 7.8 JAN-1993
5 6.7 JAN-1994
```

Comment: It's not obvious what you are asking. Can you plot monthly data? Sure. Can you plot daily data when you only have monthly data? No. What are you really trying to do?

Comment: I would like to make a anomaly temperature graph from 1990-2017. But I only have the monthly data. I found out that most example to make the anomaly graph is using daily data. So I would like to ask if I can make the anomaly graph is I only have the monthly data.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are trying to do?

```
# Make the Data Actually Useable
a<- c("1 8.2 JAN-1990", "2 5.3 JAN-1991", 
      "3 6.2 JAN-1992", "4 7.8 JAN-1993", 
      "5 6.7 JAN-1994") %>% 
  as_data_frame() %>% 
  separate(value, c("number", "temp", "month"), sep = " ") %>% 
  mutate(temp = as.numeric(temp),
         # Now Convert the Date- Assuming First of Month?
         month = lubridate::dmy(paste0("1-",month)))

# Base Way
plot(a$month, a$temp, xlab = "Month", ylab= "Temperature")

# Make the Chart in ggplot2
ggplot(a, aes(month, temp))+
  geom_point()+
  scale_x_date()
```

Comment: I would like to do some graph like the one that shows in this website.  https://www.r-bloggers.com/anomaly-detection-in-r-2/